# Save only once by loading everything in the memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to save data in 10 entity tables at once. For this reason I am loading the data in the related entity objects and saving it in the end. I am trying to check if the record exist in the database by

```
var bankContacts = entity.BankContacts.Where(bc => bc.Bank.Equals(bankObj)).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I am getting the following error: 'Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'
I don't have the value of the Bank.BankID to be able to use

```
var bankContacts = entity.BankContacts.Where(bc => bc.BankID == bankObj.BankID).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I solve this issue?
The current bank object is:
[image]

Comment: where are your entity, and the mapping ?

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons , i should rather ask .. How is the TITLE even related to the question ?!!!!!!

Comment: obviously, id would not be generated - ask yourself how will you check if record already present? - you need to compare other fields of entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line ...

```
var bankContacts = entity.BankContacts.Where(bc => bc.Bank.Equals(bankObj)).FirstOrDefault();
```

... is comparing the two bank objects with `.Equals` and EF doesn't know how to convert that to a query expression.  Remember EF is not going to run your methods like stand linq but will convert them to SQL queries for operation.  You need to compare them in another way such as `bc.Bank.Id ==` etc.  If you need to make sure all values are equal then you can write custom comparer for EF or just add multiple `.where` clauses or multiple `||` operators to test them all.

Answer (score 0):

'Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context' 
it means that only built-in data types or enums types which is converted to int are supported.

EF deosn't know how to translate your query to SQL statements to run it against your database.